# Why are ordered std::map and ordered std::set not invited to make transaction_safe?

Tags: c++, concurrency, stl, c++14, transactional-memory

As known there are Transactional Memory TS (ISO/IEC TS 19841:2015) in the Experimental C++: [Is it enough to declare a function as transaction_safe, so they can be used thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663379/is-it-enough-to-declare-a-function-as-transaction-safe-so-they-can-be-used-thre)

And `operator[]` declared as `transaction_safe` only for containers: `std::vector`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_multimap`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_multiset`, `std::deque` - Taken from n4514: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4514.pdf

> 23.4 Associative containers [associative]
>
> 23.4.4 Class template map [map]
>
> 23.4.4.1 Class template map overview [map.overview]
>
> In 23.4.4.1 [map.overview], add "transaction_safe" to the declarations
>   of all variants of the begin and end member functions and to the
>   declarations of size, max_size, and empty.

But why is not there `operator[]` declared as `transaction_safe` for `std::map` and `std::set` (but there are for `unordered_map`/`unordered_set`)?

And why there are add "transaction_safe" to the declarations of all variants of the `begin` and `end` member functions for `std::map` and `std::set`?

Iterators `begin` and `end` are very necessary for the `std::array`, `std::vector` or `std::list`, but not for an associative array. In an associative array required find or find-and-modify functions: `find`, `at`, `insert`, `erase` and `operator[]`. Without them, it does not make sense.

Why are ordered std::map and ordered std::set not invited to make transaction_safe?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the unconditional transaction-safe on `operator[]` for `unordered_meow` is a defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `unordered_meow::operator[]` is specified to be unconditionally transaction-safe is a defect.

- To start with, `unordered_set`, `unordered_multiset` and `unordered_multimap` don't even have an `operator[]` in the first place.
- `unordered_map::operator[]` must call `Hash` and `Pred`, and possibly allocate memory and construct a new key-value pair; none of these are necessarily transaction safe.

Instead, `map::operator[]`'s transaction safety is governed by the addition to [container.requirements.general]:

> Unless unconditionally specified to be transaction-safe, a function in
>   this Clause is transaction-safe if all required operations are
>   transaction-safe. [ Note: This includes operations on the element
>   type, on `std::allocator_traits`, and on `Compare`, `Pred`, or `Hash` objects,
>   depending on the respective function. -- end note ]